# Unable to create next version number sequence in App Store

Tags: app-store

I have a similar issue to others with version numbers in the App Store being unable to upload but don't see a solution for mine.

I created version 1.21, which is a published app. I now realize that the format is supposed to be 1.2.1

Then I tried to create version 1.3 but it says the 1.21 is higher.

How can I get back on the 1.x version numbering format?

Thanks in advance,

~eric

~eric

Answer (score 1):

`1.21` is obvisously higher than `1.3`.

I think your only option would be version number `1.22` or higher.